# Get a limited number of records in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to query Firebase for records that match my conditions, but I want to only get a few of them.  I am using Swift. Is this possible?  For example, I have a query like this:

```
firebaseReference.child("array").queryOrdered(byChild: "userType").queryEqual(toValue: "family").observe(.value, with: { (snapshotVec) -> Void in
            Storage.shared.numFamsInVec = snapshotVec.childrenCount
}
```

This will retrieve all the records whose `userType` is `family`, but say I only want to get half of them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly is. The magic is in the [Firebase documentation for filtering data on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data):

```
firebaseReference
    .child("array")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "userType")
    .queryEqual(toValue: "family")
    .queryLimited(toFirs: 10)
    .observe(.value, with: { (snapshotVec) -> Void in
            Storage.shared.numFamsInVec = snapshotVec.childrenCount
    }
```

Also see the [Firebase reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseQuery#-querylimitedtofirst), which contains the magic incantation for Swift 3.